# Spring:Using Controller actions in one JSP file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVc project. I have a single JSP page, with two forms. Both these forms are handled by 2 different controllers, and they have separate database tables, seperate service methods. But I would like to individually select information(notes) which the user is adding and save them. I am posting both of my controller, JSP file, and the error message. Kindly let me know what might be going wrong. Thank you for your time.

PersonController :

```
  @Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService ps){
        this.personService = ps;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p){


            //new person, add it
            this.personService.addPerson(p);

        return "redirect:/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") String id){

        this.personService.removePerson(id);
        return "redirect:/persons";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("person", this.personService.getPersonById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

}
```

keyactivitiesController.java

```
@Controller
public class KeyActivitiesController {

    private KeyActivitiesService keyActivitiesService;

    @Qualifier(value="keyActivitiesService")

    public void setKeyActivitiesService(KeyActivitiesService keyActivitiesService){this.keyActivitiesService = keyActivitiesService;}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/keynotice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listNotices(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("keyactivities", new KeyActivities());
        model.addAttribute("listNotices", this.keyActivitiesService.listNotices());
        return "keyactivities";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/keynotice/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("keyactivities") KeyActivities p){


        //new person, add it
        this.keyActivitiesService.addKeyNotice(p);

        return "redirect:/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/removeNotice/{id}")
    public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") String id){

        this.keyActivitiesService.removeNotice(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/editNotice/{id}")
    public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("keyactivities", this.keyActivitiesService.getNoticenById(id));
        model.addAttribute("keyactivities", this.keyActivitiesService.listNotices());
        return "keyactivities";
    }

}
```

person.jsp

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/person/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
<table>
    <c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="id">
                <spring:message text="ID"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
            <form:hidden path="id" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    </c:if>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="name">
                <spring:message text="Name"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="name" />
        </td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">
            <c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
                <input type="submit"
                    value="<spring:message text="Edit Notice"/>" />
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${empty person.name}">
                <input type="submit"
                    value="<spring:message text="Add Notice"/>" />
            </c:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>    
</form:form>

<br>
<c:url var="addAction" value="/keynotice/add" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="keyactivities">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty keyactivities.keynotice}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="keynotice">
                    <spring:message text="Keynotice"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="keynotice" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
                <c:if test="${!empty keyactivities.keynotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit Notice"/>" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty keyactivities.keynotice}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add Notice"/>" />
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'keyactivities' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:130)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:120)

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:465)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refactor this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listPersons(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
    model.addAttribute("keyactivities", new KeyActivities());
    model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
    return "person";
}
```

The error is that after post either form, you will not have `keyactivities` in the `model`

Comment: Thanks man, Worked like a charm...Just one question, if I want to add more forms, just like I have used 2 in the above, I can just add the model attribute and they will work, right?

Comment: I know, its kinda emergency. THanks. Marking your answer.